# Using apache to filter desktop and mobile browsers?

Tags: apache, mobile, filter

What's the best way to filter mobile users to a separate web page, through apache?

Ideally, when the user browses `www.example.com` from a desktop, they get `/sites/desktop` and when they browse `www.example.com` from a phone, they get `/sites/mobile`. I'd like this to work as a sort of pass-through, so I could refer to absolute paths on both the mobile and desktop web pages.

I looked at the [Apache Mobile Filter](http://www.apachemobilefilter.org/Apache_Mobile_Filter/Welcome.php), but the documentation is almost non-existent and the tutorials are woefully incomplete. Is there an easy way to do what i'm trying to achieve? If AMF is the solution, are there good tutorials out there somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/

Answer (score 1):

Did you notice the dev (Idel Fuschini) changed the site recently and added a wiki? If you haven't solved your problem yet, I strongly suggest you try AMF. You seem to be needing the [AMFSwitcher module](http://wiki.apachemobilefilter.org/index.php/AMFSwitcher). I've been using AMF for a few years now and it's really good. Idel is italian and doesn't speak perfect english, but I think the docs have improved greatly from what we used a couple of years ago.

Answer (score -1):

I believe [this](http://www.apachemobilefilter.org/Apache_Mobile_Filter/Welcome.php) website has alot to say about that. It looks like a project directly attacking that problem.

Comment: Yeah. Try following those docs and get back to me. I'm fairly certain the author doesn't have a proper command of English.